# GAE jinja2: how to automatically pop up a new window in a browser?

Tags: html, jinja2

Is there a way to automatically pop up a new window in a browser in gae python jinja2? That is, a way for doing what JavaScript command window.open() does?
The new pop window should be open when user click in a button to query datastore. So he can query in the new window, select a query result and come back to the previous window after closing the poped window.

Comment: When do you want the window to open? When the the user clicks on something, or some other time? If it's just on clicks, you can always use `target="_blank"` in your anchor tags, but otherwise I suspect you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: is not related to gae python jinja2. that is problem about html.
`<a target="_blank" href="link">here</a>`

Comment: I clarified the question. It's a pop up window. I think it is a jinja2 question, its related with templates issue.

Comment: I am also searching for same, controlling popup via jinja2 templates. I want this for controlling facebook popup windows as I am not able to capture click event with javascript and receive response as GET URL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you'd need to do it in JavaScript. The page where the popup was initiated from would need to be updated with values chosen on the popup (doing this with JavaScript would be relatively simple). You could still use jinja template in the popup by doing a callback to the server to fetch the page you want to show in the popup.

Good luck, 
Rob